# Function to copy formatting from one cell, value from another?

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

I'm very, very new to all this, and this community seems very helpful when it comes to writing VBA functions etc. I've been looking around the site for a similar question, and couldn't find anything dealing with my particular issue.

I need to create a function which copies the formatting from one cell and the values from another cell, and combines them into a single output.

For some context, I have a sheet which finds numbers formatted as [00:00:00], convert them to a total time value (hh:mm:ss) and adds a common value to each of these. Not all the initial values are numeric, others are text and need to retain their bolding/italic properties in the final output. So what I'm looking for is a way to copy the value from a cell (let's say G2) and the formatting from a different cell (Let's say A2), and combine them for a final output.

My terrible coding skills produced this:

```
Function Copy_Format(cell1, cell2)
    Dim cell1 As String, cell2 As String
    Range("cell1").Copy
    Range("cell2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("cell2").Copy
    Range("output").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Function
```

I want "cell1" to be the cell to copy the format from, "cell2" to be where the values come from, and "cell3" to be the cell the function is inserted into.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated! The overall goal is to make this a one-step process, as this will end up being distributed to over a hundred people with little to no experience in Excel.

Thanks!!
FFstack

Comment: If you are using this as a UDF in the worksheet directly it will not work.  A Function called from the worksheet cannot change the format of a cell, even itself.

Comment: So I'd have to have this as a second step? Like insert the information then run a macro to fix it?

Comment: Yes, but then a sub would be better than a function.

Comment: Rats! I was hoping to make it a one-step process. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function CopyFormat(cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range)
CopyFormat = Format(cell2, cell1.NumberFormat)
End Function
```

- When you do a function, no need to ReDim the variables defined in the function itself
- Also, when outputting in a function, set the name of the function to the desired result (i.e. `CopyFormat = ...`)
- When refering to a variable in a range, no need for quotes (i.e. `Range(cell1)` instead of `Range("cell1")`)
- Copy/pasting in a function is probably not ideal: this method just grabs the `.NumberFormat` property and applies it with the `Format` function

If using the Function on an excel worksheet, it can be put in like `=CopyFormat(A1,B1)`, otherwise if in VBA, just leave out the `=`

**Edit:** If you want the bold, etc., copied over, that isn't possible with a function (as Scott explained above). It seems like the easiest way to do that would be to use a Sub with criteria, like so:

```
Sub Copy_Format(cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range, cell3 As Range)
Dim sel As Range
Set sel = Selection

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

cell1.Copy
cell3.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

cell2.Copy
cell3.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

sel.Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This Sub could not be called from the worksheet, but can be called through VBA like this:

```
Sub test()
Call Copy_Format(Range("A1"), Range("B1"), Range("C1"))
End Sub
```

If you had specific cells to run, you could make a loop to do the whole column, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tips!! I don't think I explained well enough, I've got the numbers in the right format, how I want the output, but I need to copy the formatting, bolding and italics, to the final outputted cell. That;s why I started with the copy/paste within the function.

Comment: Oh, for that you can't use a function (like Scott said). I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This copies the format from cell1 to cell2 and then the value of cell2 to output:

```
Function Copy_Format(cell1, cell2, output)
    cell1.Copy
    cell2.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    cell2.Copy
    output.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    Copy_Format = output
End Function
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: I was hoping to use this as a function so I could use it in conjunction with the other formulas in the sheet, is there a way to change the output so it's the  return for the formula, then I could identify cell1 and cell2 in the formula?

Comment: You can make it a function and return output.